# How to execute template tooklit script?

Tags: perl, report, reporting

I would like to execute a template toolkit script with some dummy data in order to quickly test functionality. For example, an script that adds a date into an excel.

```
[%- MODE=xlsx %]
[%-
    X = XLSX;
    X.newWorksheet('My Report');
    USE date;
    # use current time and default format
    X.add(date.format)
    X.end()
    X.print();
-%]
```

Is it any interpreter or tool (installed or online) to execute this type of scripts? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Head to [tutorial](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Datafile.html) section of _template toolkit_ and follow the tutorial.

Comment: [Download](http://www.template-toolkit.org/download/index.html) section of TTS.

Answer (score 2):

The module installs the [`tpage` command line tool](https://metacpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/view/lib/Template/Tools/tpage.pod).

```
$ cat greeting.tt
Hello, [% target %]!

$ tpage --define target=World greeting.tt
Hello, World!
```

Of course, you could also write a small Perl script.

```perl
use Template qw( );
my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process('greeting.tt', {
   target => 'World',
})
   or die($tt->error());
```